# GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") versus "name=DefaultConnection"

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I  noticed some people use

```
var constring = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")!;
options.UseSqlServer(constring);
```

and some other people just use

```
options.UseSqlServer("name=DefaultConnection");
```

Are there any differences?

Note: Both read `DefaultConnection` key in `appsettings.json`.

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "server=.;database=MyDb;integrated security=true"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference rly, the second call

```
options.UseSqlServer("name=DefaultConnection");
```

Will try to parse any string found in the connectionStrings config section, with a name of DefaultConnection, they are the same thing, but reading the config explicitly could be a "better" way, as it does not abstract the way that the confiiguration is parsed and set imo